# Bi-Directional binding to radio button within a radio group -> Max Call Stack

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` exception if i try to make a bidirectional binding between a property and a radio button.

I created a playground example: tinyurl.com/hfl9gy8

If I try to toogle the property by the `toggle` button I am getting the exception. This happens only from `true` to `false`. `false` to `true` works perfectly.

Is it a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several `qx.ui.form.RadioButtons`and add them to a `qx.ui.form.RadioGroup` with default properties, then the group manager enforces that exactly one radio group item hast to be selected.

So if you take only one radio button from the group, in your playground sample the radio button labeled red, and set it to false, then the group manager does not allow that, because then there would be no selection (neither red nor green) at all. Deselecting the red radio button does not mean that the green one will be selected automatically.

Binding only one boolean value (false/true) to only one radio button in a radio group does not work here.

You could set the property `allowEmptySelection` to `true` for the `qx.ui.form.RadioGroup`, which will make your playground sample work, but only by deselectong and selecting the red button, having no button selected at all in the radio group.

Conclusion: a radio group is not something you could "toggle".

Comment: I thought that i have missed something like that. I bound the second RadioButton also to the negated Property. Here is the working Playground: tinyurl.com/zktnker Thanks!